# Changing multiple attributes using javascript using intervals?

Tags: javascript, jquery, glow

I'm trying to achieve something similar to [jQuery Glow](http://ajaxian.com/archives/jquery-glow) or [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3LCdA/).

Specifically I was thinking of a start on load and lasting 10 seconds with the javascript executing at intervals of 100 milliseconds. What's supposed to happen is the background-color or element A will change using a gradient range (start #000 and end #fff) while the opacity of element B will change (start 0 and end 1). So every 100 milliseconds the opacity will increase by 1 (0.01, 0.02, ..., 1.0) and end. All the while element A's background will step along the gradient from #000 to #fff.

I can see by the jQuery Glow that this functionality shouldn't be too difficult, but piecing it together isn't proving that intuitive. That js looks pretty geared towards hovering and links, not defining different values onLoad and ending at a predetermined time.

How could I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at jQuery's `.animate()` method?

Comment: +1 for the nice links. perfect for my current assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setTimeout is no-longer your only option in JavaScript animation.

Check out setAnimationFrame in HTML5Rocks, by Paul Irish. Read about it [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/animations/).

> buttery smooth 60 frames per second.

[Scroll this page](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/animations/post.html), and...

> avoid animations that result in reflow-repaint loops; update your rAF
>   calls to expect a high resolution timestamp as the first parameter;

Lastly,

> Get the full rundown of this at: requestAnimationFrame API: now with
>   [sub-millisecond precision](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/05/requestAnimationFrame-API-now-with-sub-millisecond-precision)

Also, nnnnnn is correct. A major strength of jQuery is effects.

But, there is more to the JSWorld than just jQuery, much more.

For starters check out [CreativeJS.com](http://creativejs.com/).

It is WebGL, but more importantly: three.js (follow @mrdoob).

[ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/) is simply enterprise strength UI, animated interactions.

And [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) is simply the most advanced SVG, for now.

Other graphical solutions worthy of mention are: D3.js, HTML5 Canvas, and CSS3 Transforms.

EDIT: [I thought Adobe Edge was cool](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/edge/). It is an entire new metaphor in HTML Animation Generation, with a keyframe interface... accept, critics couldn't get past the non-semantic DIV's of the beta. I think we will hear more from that team on some advanced HTML animation generator... [Yup, they got some new stuff!](http://edge.adobe.com/)

Hope that helps.
All the best!
Nash

Comment: Yeah I used to get hung up on non-semantic divs as well. Especially since there were many times I didn't need a single one. Then I would noticed this cool js and take a look and it was four div wrappers around a single element. Eventually I got over that and just said it comes with the territory if I'm not going to learn all the js myself.

Comment: +1 to you sir. Good point. One could imagine a natural evolution into HTML5 and CSS3 automation upon a keyframe. I.e, div-itus, less necessary. Thx. Nash

Answer (score 0):

Try [Fading Effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/) and use it with `setTimeout`. You'll have to experiment a bit and I think it will work :)